Dynamic Routes NextJS and Firebase Hosting
I want to deploy my nextJS application to my firebase hosting, which works fine, all except my one dynamic route that throws a 404 everytime, or just navigates to my home page with the url.

I have tried **every ****possible **way, without any luck. I need assistance please, maybe I am missing something somewhere.
My URL Looks like this
https://my-hosting-domain.com/shop/product/%5Bid%5D?_rsc=9ehs5

{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/shop/product/**",
      "destination": "/shop/product/[id]"
    }]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "remoteconfig": {},
  "functions": [{
    "source": "functions",
    "codebase": "default",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "config": {
      "email": {
        "user": "here-lies-a-email",
        "pass": "here-lies-a-password"
      }
    }
  }]
}


My Firebase.json file

  /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
  const nextConfig = {
    env: {
      PUBLIC_URL: "https://my-hosting-domain.com/",
    },
    reactStrictMode: true,
    trailingSlash: true,
  };

  export default nextConfig;


My next.config.mjs
When I build and deploy my site
Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
• non-static component /shop/product/[id]/page
My dynamic route location
src/app/shop/product/[id]/page.js
My Link when I click on an item
   <Link
    prefetch={true}
    href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/shop/product/[id]`}
    as={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/shop/product/${data.id}`}>

This link is in src/components/Product/index.js
If Any one can help and point out what I'm missing that would be appreciated. Thank you
text
text
